# Realm calls stop working after ios app goes idle

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

I have an odd issue that has taken a large amount of my time in google searches. I may be using the wrong wording to search for this.

When my iOS Swift application is left open for a long period of time (idle timer gets disabled on specific screens) the app seems to time out somewhere and when returning to one of my main screens, no data gets populated from Realm. This screen works fine 100% of the time during normal use, but if the app is ever left on for 10+ minutes without interaction, realm will stop functioning all together.

I use the below function from viewWillAppear on the screen I am speaking of and a table is built from this data. That table gets built as empty.

```
class func getAvailableEvents() -> Results<Event> {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let events = realm.objects(Event.self)
    return events
}
```

I have attempted to use realm.refresh() to fix this issue, but that doesn't work either. Is there some realm command I need to run to keep it from shutting out after long idle times or is there something special I need to do to re-initialize it? Breakpointing on this function and printing out the events prints 0 data, calling other realm functions gives nothing, and causes no error. So I guess it can create the realm instance, but it can't read it right.

Comment: Have you tried storing Realm as a field variable?

Comment: Yes, original implementation was standard functions in my RealmManager class where I set up a shared instance and ran 1 realm, but someone had suggested I use class functions for cleaner code and destruction of instance not in use.

Comment: I don't know if the Results keeps the Realm open if the instance is closed by de-init :D not sure how realm-cocoa handles this

Comment: I'll convert back to a singleton and do some tests with that to make sure in the mean time.